# Suppress C++17 warnings from LSP client in neovim

Tags: c++, neovim, language-server-protocol, neovim-plugin

I installed the LSP client for C++ development using the plugin manager "packer" in neovim. My lua config was almost exclusively copied
from this website:

[LSP in Neovim](https://dev.to/vonheikemen/getting-started-with-neovims-native-lsp-client-in-the-year-of-2022-the-easy-way-bp3)

When working with modern CPP however, I get warning messages. The native LSP client does not support modern CPP apparently?

For example this line of code uses nested namespaces:

`namespace Tuple::Person`

The *warning message* I get looks like this: Nested namespace definition is a C++17 extension; define each namespace separately.

Structured bindings also don't work:

`auto [name, age] = Tuple::Person::getPersonData();`

The *warning message*: Decomposition declarations are a C++17 extension.

Does anyone know how to fix this?
In case you don't, do you have other recommendations on how to integrate clangd, clangtidy or in general C++ auto completion in neovim? I tried using YouCompleteMe, but that didn't work for me as well. Thanks for any help or recommendations in advance!

Comment: You may get better, faster feedback on how to configure it for C++17 if you ask on the LSP discussion forums.

Comment: @Eljay Thanks. Where are those discussion forums? As you can see... I'm a new contributor.. :)

Comment: In the link you provided, click on the link within that where it mentions "discussion tab" on github.

Comment: What LSP server is this? Clangd?

Comment: yes exactly....

Comment: Do you have a compile_flags.txt or compile_commands.json file? You can set -std=c++17 in there and it should work.

Comment: @cigien No, this is not what I meant.. In the editor itself (nvim), there are warnings visible. Using g++ 12.2.0 compiling C++23 is not a problem. No warnings occur there..

Comment: That's what I mean. The neovim lsp will look for the appropriate compilation commands in  specific places, e.g. compile_flags.txt. Try adding this file and see if it works.

Comment: @cigien You're right. It was as easy as that! Thanks ;)